# How do I make this simple proof better (and more correct?)

Tags: proof-writing

Let $x$ and $y$ be real numbers. If $x\cdot{y}>\frac{1}{2}$, then $x^2+y^2>1$.

Proof: We will prove with the direct method. Let $x$ and $y$ be real numbers. Since
$$ x\cdot{y}>\frac{1}{2} $$
it follows that
$$ 2xy>1,$$
which means
$$x^2+y^2 \geq 2xy.$$
Therefore,
$$ x^2+y^2>1. $$

Comment: I can't follow this at all. $a$ means $x$ and $b$ means $y$! And everything is backwards! How does $$a^2+\left(\frac{1}{2a}\right)^2 > 1$$ follow from $a \cdot b > \dfrac{1}{2}$? What's this "which thus allows", where you should have "which thus proves" (but it doesn't)?

Comment: Yeah, it's all wrong, I know that. That's why I was asking how to make it better, and below you'll see that a few people obviously answered...

Comment: But they have not referred to your proof at all, except to recommend a couple of irrelevant changes of wording.

Comment: How about now? I've re-written it, let me know what you think.

Comment: That's much better! But your "which means" is wrong. $x^2+y^2\ge 2xy$ is not a consequence of $2xy > 1$, it is true in its own right (and you should briefly explain why).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Write $0\le (x-y)^2=x^2-2xy+y^2$, hence $1<2xy\le x^2+y^2$.

Comment: I totally get how you went to $1<2xy$, but why compare it as $1<2xy\leq{x}^2+y^2$ ?

Comment: Write $0\le x^2-2xy+y^2$ as $2xy\le x^2+y^2$.

Comment: Oh I see, so given that $1<2xy$, we may say also that $x^2+y^2>1$ can be rewritten as $x^2+y^2>2xy$, substituting $2xy$ for $1$, which also means that, as you've already written, $x^2+y^2>2xy>1$. Thanks!

Comment: @bd1251252 If $a\ge b$ and $b>c$, then always $a>c$ (what you wrote sounds pretty confusing).

Comment: Out of curiosity, is it appropriate to say that, given $xy>\frac{1}{2}$, $x^2+y^2>1\longrightarrow x^2+y^2>2xy>1$, or should I use biconditional to say that $x^2+y^2>1 \longleftrightarrow x^2+y^2>2xy>1$ ?

Comment: @bd1251252 Your logic is entirely messed up. It's not that $xy>1/2$ and $x^2+y^2>1$ imply $x^2+y^2>2xy>1$ (recall that you want to prove that $x^2+y^2>1$ so you can't put this in the assumptions). You start with $x^2+y^2\ge 2xy$ and $2xy>1$ and from those two things you conclude that $x^2+y^2>1$.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I figure it's gonna burn for a while until I figure things out, and how to draw conclusions from the statements.

Answer (score 2):

Since $x,y\not=0\Rightarrow x^2,y^2\gt 0$, by AM-GM inequality, we have
$$x^2+y^2\ge 2\sqrt{x^2y^2}=2|xy|=2xy\gt 2\cdot \frac 12=1.$$

Comment: Also a neat answer. I had to look up AM-GM inequality because I had never heard of it before, interesting!

Comment: @bd1251252: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means).

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably going to be a little grammatically picky, but I personally think proper grammar is good in a proof, (and an analysis lecturer drilled it into our class to use 'proper English sentences' where the maths would read as part of the sentence).

- I would remove the comma after the first line of mathematical notation say something like 'we have/get', instead of 'therefore'.
- 'If we substitute...' (no and)

Comment: Thanks! I'm just learning how to write basic proofs and things like this from people who have done more than I are really great.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem is the "which means".

$2xy>1$ doesn't imply $x^2+y^2≥2xy$ in any way.

$x^2+y^2≥2xy$ is true because $x^2-2xy+y^2 = (x-y)^2 ≥ 0$, which means $x^2+y^2≥2xy$.

Answer (score -1):

There is a much simpler proof.

Since $xy > \frac{1}{2}$, $x$ and $y$ must be non zero numbers, which are both positive or negative.

Suppose $x>0$ and $y>0$.

If $x>1$, then also $x^2>1$, and $x^2 +y^2>x^2>1$ is obvious.

Take $0<x\leq 1$ and $y>0$.

Since $0<x\leq 1$, the function $f$ with $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$   is well defined.  Let  $g$ be the function with $g(x)=\frac{1}{2x}, \ 0<x\leq 1$.

It can be easily proved that the function h with $h(x)=-x+\sqrt{2}, \ 0<x\leq 1$ 
      has a graph which is a line tangent to the graphs of $f$ and $g$ at the point
      $(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$.

One can also verify easily that $f$ is a concave function and that $g$ is a convex funtion. Therefore the tangent line $h$ is above the graph of $f$ and below the graph of $g$. 
      So if  $0<x\leq 1$,the previous remark implies that  $f(x)\leq h(x)\leq g(x)$ and  $\sqrt{1-x^2}\leq \frac{1}{2x}$.

Now, the proposition we want to prove is obvious: If $xy > \frac{1}{2}$, then $y>\frac{1}{2x}$, 
      and $\frac{1}{2x} \geq \sqrt{1-x^2}$ from the previous inequality, hence 
      $y> \frac{1}{2x} \geq \sqrt{1-x^2}$. Consequently, $y>\sqrt{1-x^2}$, which implies
      $y^2>1-x^2$ and therefore $x^2+y^2>1.$

The case $x<0$ and $y<0$ is similar.

Comment: That doesn't look simpler than what was posted almost 4 years ago.